# Full Join on two tables with criteria on both

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables with a matching key. Some records exist on both tables, others only exist on one or the other. What I cannot for the life of me figure out is how to add criteria to both tables when doing a full outer join.

Table A (EDIT: with criteria)

```
+---------------------------+
| ID, AREA, STATUS, YEAR     |
+----------------------------+
| ID1, AA,  YES,  1980       |
| ID2, BB,  NO,   1990       |
| ID3, CC,  YES,  1950       |
| ID4, DD,  NO,   1900       |
```

Table B (EDIT: with criteria)

```
+--------------------------+
| ID, ZONE, CODE, TIME     |
+--------------------------+
| ID1, FF,  1,  12:00      |
| ID5, HH,  1,  11:11      |
| ID6, II,  1,  13:00      |
```

Desired Join

```
 +------------------------------------------+
 | ID, AREA, STATUS, YEAR, ZONE, CODE, TIME |
 +------------------------------------------+
 | ID1, AA,  YES,  1980,    FF,  1,   2000  |
 | ID2, BB,  NO,   1990,    n/a, n/a,  n/a  |
 | ID3, CC,  YES,  1950     n/a, n/a,  n/a  |
 | ID4, DD,  NO,   1900     n/a, n/a,  n/a  |
 | ID5, n/a, n/a,  n/a,     HH,  1,   2001  |
 | ID6, n/a, n/a,   n/a,    II,  1,   2000  |
```

So far I have the following code. It is returning everything for me besides ID5 and ID6, **for some reason it won't bring rows in the join where col in Table A are null (n/a).**

```
SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR, B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME
FROM TableA A 
FULL JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND /* criteria for B */ (B.ZONE > XX AND B.CODE >= XX)
WHERE /* criteria for A */ A.YEAR > XXXX
```

**Am I putting my criteria in the incorrect locations? How can I do a Full Join but also apply criteria to both TableA and TableB ?**

Comment: is MySQL actually relevant as a tag?

Comment: MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN` so this question is obviously not about MySQL.  @David . . . Please tag your question only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the scope of the full join I suggest that you use subqueries to implement the wanted conditions using where clauses, such as this:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A(
>    ID     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
>   ,AREA   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
>   ,STATUS VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
>   ,YEAR   INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO A(ID,AREA,STATUS,YEAR) VALUES ('ID1','AA','YES',1980);
> INSERT INTO A(ID,AREA,STATUS,YEAR) VALUES ('ID2','BB','NO',1990);
> INSERT INTO A(ID,AREA,STATUS,YEAR) VALUES ('ID3','CC','YES',1950);
> INSERT INTO A(ID,AREA,STATUS,YEAR) VALUES ('ID4','DD','NO',1900);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE B(
>    ID   VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
>   ,ZONE VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
>   ,CODE BIT  NOT NULL
>   ,TIME VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO B(ID,ZONE,CODE,TIME) VALUES ('ID1','FF',1,'12:00');
> INSERT INTO B(ID,ZONE,CODE,TIME) VALUES ('ID5','HH',1,'11:11');
> INSERT INTO B(ID,ZONE,CODE,TIME) VALUES ('ID6','II',1,'13:00');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR, B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME
> FROM A 
> FULL JOIN B
> ON A.ID = B.ID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID   | AREA | STATUS | YEAR | ID   | ZONE | CODE | TIME 
> :--- | :--- | :----- | ---: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :----
> ID1  | AA   | YES    | 1980 | ID1  | FF   | True | 12:00
> ID2  | BB   | NO     | 1990 | null | null | null | null 
> ID3  | CC   | YES    | 1950 | null | null | null | null 
> ID4  | DD   | NO     | 1900 | null | null | null | null 
> null | null | null   | null | ID5  | HH   | True | 11:11
> null | null | null   | null | ID6  | II   | True | 13:00
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A(ID,AREA,STATUS,YEAR) VALUES ('ID10','AA','YES',1940);
>
> INSERT INTO B(ID,ZONE,CODE,TIME) VALUES ('ID6','II',-7,'01:30');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR, B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME
> FROM (
>       select * from A where year > 1940
>      ) AS A 
> FULL JOIN (
>      select * from b where code > 0 or time > '12:00'
>      ) B
> ON A.ID = B.ID
> ```

> ```
> ID   | AREA | STATUS | YEAR | ID   | ZONE | CODE | TIME 
> :--- | :--- | :----- | ---: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :----
> ID1  | AA   | YES    | 1980 | ID1  | FF   | True | 12:00
> null | null | null   | null | ID5  | HH   | True | 11:11
> null | null | null   | null | ID6  | II   | True | 13:00
> null | null | null   | null | ID6  | II   | True | 01:30
> ID2  | BB   | NO     | 1990 | null | null | null | null 
> ID3  | CC   | YES    | 1950 | null | null | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=47ffa786dd10f5e26f9e566ca2c3c203)*

Comment: Thank you so much Paul! That did what I needed. Very new to SQL but your example showed me how subqueries were the answer here. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Also note the importance of sample data.  I needed the rows not wanted in the result to demonstrate how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think as your Desired Join Table, the query should be ended after the first join condition.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR, B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME
FROM TableA A 
FULL JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Edited :

```
SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR, B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME
FROM (SELECT A.ID, A.AREA, A.STATUS, A.YEAR FROM TableA A WHERE A.YEAR > XXXX) A
FULL JOIN (SELECT B.ID, B.ZONE, B.CODE, B.TIME FROM TableB WHERE B.ZONE > XX AND B.CODE >= XX) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: I edited my post to clarify, TableA and TableB examples already have criteria applied. Where would I put the criteria for them when I am trying to do a join? Without any criteria the tables return 400K rows.

Comment: Thanks @ Nguyễn! I see your code correlates with the example and answer Paul provided above. My apologies if my original post wasn't clear. Thanks for your answer here, I really appreciate how it's helping me learn this new language!